# Cucumber Capture Custom Expressions Java - How to allow for string entry in feature steps?

Tags: java, cucumber-java

We are attempting to switch over entirely to Cucumber expressions and no longer use Regex.  My question is it possible to create a type that allows for a String entry in the feature file?

For example: (the "second" user is ) instead of (the second user is )

Here is the custom paramType method I am using.

```
registry.defineParameterType(new ParameterType<>(
                "universalKey",
                "1st|first|2nd|second|3rd|third",
                String.class,
                (String arg) -> arg
        ));
```

Currently it allows for no strings entry but I would like to keep it with quotes to avoid having to redo a lot of feature files/steps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up figuring out although not using it but the following is how we did it:

```
registry.defineParameterType(new ParameterType<>(
            "numbers",
            "\"(1st)"\|\"(first)"\|\"(2nd)"\|\"(second)"\",
            String.class,
            (String arg) -> arg
    ));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try escaping the double quotes with a backslash '\'.

```
the \"second\" user is
```

Refer here - https://cucumber.io/docs/cucumber/cucumber-expressions/#escaping